# How to run string sequentially in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

i have a ploblem :(

```
var cleanExpressions = [I, am, a, boy]
```

before i wrote code

Order is important.

```
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cleanExpressions.length; i += 1) {
  result.push(
    /*mutatition*/
    AddExpressionWord({ 
      variables: {
        passageExpressionId,
        wordId: cleanExpressions[i]
      }
    })
  );
}
await Promise.all(result);
```

but sometimes the order is messed up and stored in the DB.

like that

```
outPut: [i, am, boy, a]
```

How can I get it in order?

Comment: What is `AddExpressionWord`? What is `outPut`?

Comment: AddExpressionWord is just grapqhl Query like that "axios.post"
Sequentially send words to backend

and output is data is stored in DB.

Comment: You don't send them sequentially: you send them all at once and then wait while all 4 parallel requests complete.

Comment: I guess you have a bunch of async operations and you wish to maintain the order. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Promise.all` use `for of` and `await` to do them sequentially:

```
let results = [];
for (let item of cleanExpressions) {
  let response = await AddExpressionWord({ 
    variables: {
      passageExpressionId,
      wordId: item
    }
  });
  results.push(response);
}
```